# Subsetting data, if the column entry contains letters

Tags: r, string, character, subset

I have data as follows:

```
DT <- as.data.frame(c("1","2", "3", "A", "B"))
names(DT)[1] <- "charnum"
```

What I want is quite simple, but I could not find an example on it on stackoverflow.

I want to split the dataset into two. `DT1` with all the rows for which `DT$charnum` has numbers and  `DT2` with all the rows for which `DT$charnum` has letters. I tried something like:

```
DT1 <- DT[is.numeric(as.numeric(DT$charnum)),]
```

But that gives:

```
[1] 1 2 3 A B
Levels: 1 2 3 A B
```

Desired result:

```
> DT1
  charnum
1         1
2         2
3         3

> DT2
  charnum
1         A
2         B
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to separate the two types of data that you have and then separate the two datasets.

```
result <- split(DT, grepl('^\\d+$', DT$charnum))
DT1 <- type.convert(result[[1]])
DT1

#  charnum
#4       A
#5       B

DT2 <- type.convert(result[[2]])
DT2
#  charnum
#1       1
#2       2
#3       3
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
DT %>% 
   group_split(grp = str_detect(charnum, "\\d+"), .keep = FALSE) %>% 
   map(type.convert, as.is = TRUE)
```